# SharePoint 2013 FBA + ADFS Proxy

Tags: forms-authentication, adfs

I have a complicated scenario with ADFS.

It's possible I have a Web Application with Forms Based Authentication and ADFS Proxy?

If true, please give the examples or articles.

Comment: If you want two authentication on same sit then you have to extend web application on different zone and give them different authentication.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you would attempt to do that (and SAML is authenticated via Windows auth anyhow). Using the Web Application Proxy provides you with that FBA interface.

Comment: I need my user insert the user and password in FBA and this be pre-authenticate with ADFS before the user access physically the sharepoint. You understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement Web Application Proxy. You can optionally implement ADFS 3.0 using a non-claims aware relaying party trust in order to not need to convert SharePoint to using SAML authentication.

This is a great guide on how to do this. [Part 2​ - Securely publishing SharePoint externally using Web Application Proxy ​(WAP)](http://www.brightstarr.com/sharepoint-technology-and-application-insights/securely-publishing-sharepoint-externally-using-web-application-proxy-part-2). Using this method will provide a pre-authentication experience for your users (FBA).

Comment: Thank you very much, it was exactly this concept that I did not know.